# Bash script live output executed from PHP

Tags: php, bash, shell, shell-exec

I'm trying to execute a bash script from php and getting its output in real time.

I am applying the answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107147/php-reading-shell-exec-live-output):

However they are not working for me.

When I invoke the .sh script on this way, it works fine:

```
<?php
  $output = shell_exec("./test.sh");
  echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

However, when doing:

```
<?php
  echo '<pre>';
  passthru(./test.sh);
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

or:

```
<?php
  while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any
  $proc = popen(./test.sh, 'r');
  echo '<pre>';
  while (!feof($proc))
    {
    echo fread($proc, 4096);
    @ flush();
    }
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

I have no output in my browser.

I also tried to call the variable instead of the script in both cases, I mean:

```
<?php
  $output = shell_exec("./test.sh");
  echo '<pre>';
  passthru($output);
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

This is my test.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami
sleep 3
dmesg
```

Comment: the filename should be quoted - `passthru("./test.sh");` - it doesn't work even like this?

Comment: @ewcz It does work with my test.sh example, thanks. However it doesn't work for the actual script I want to use. At least this is a beginning and I can analyze further from now on. If you write your comment as answer I will validate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following:

```
<?php
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

$cmd = "bash /path/to/test.sh";

$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),   // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),   // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w")    // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
);


$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath('./'), array());

if (is_resource($process)) {

    while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
        print $s;

    }
}

?>
```

Change test.sh to:

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami
sleep 3
ls /
```

**Explanation:**

dmesg requires permissions. You need to grant webserver's user permissions for that. In my case apache2 is being run via www-data user.

`ob_implicit_flush(true)`: Turns implicit flushing on. Implicit flushing will result in a flush operation after every output call, so that explicit calls to `flush()` will no longer be needed.

`ob_end_flush()`: Turns off output buffering, so we see results immediately.

Comment: `stream_select()` + `stream_get_contents()` are better suited for the job, since `fgets()` stops reading when a newline comes (which is very likely to happen). Check my previous answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37526704/1957951